# Does Firebase support BDD Testing with a custom testrunner?

Tags: firebase, web, mobile, bdd, firebase-test-lab

We're using BDD automated tests with a custom test runner. I've been trying to find any information if Firebase supports this for mobile or web app tests.
Does anyone know or have any experience with this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Everything that Firebase Test Lab does is well documented: https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab

Comment: What type of BDD framework? Are you able to run it via gradle by providing a custom instrumentation test runner, or is it a stand-alone runner that doesn't leverage the existing test runners that Android provides?

Comment: Hi Maik, yes it's a custom test runner running with gradle. Have you tried this on Firebase?

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't give much detail on what test runner/framework you are using, and how it works underneath, if it uses instrumentation, ... .

If you use a custom instrumentation runner that hooks up like below in your `build.gradle`, and doesn't need custom output to be parsed to understand if it failed or succeeded.

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        testInstrumentationRunner "com.example.MyTestRunner"
    }
    ...
}
```

Then it should just work out of the box in Test Lab with the instrumentation test type.

If your test runner writes files on the device that you need for investigating test failures, run your test with `gcloud` and specify `--directories-to-pull` to get them copied to the GCS bucket.

```
gcloud firebase test android run \
  --app myapp.apk \
  --test mytests.apk \
  --device model=walleye,version=28 \
  --directories-to-pull=/sdcard/myartifacts
```